# Where can I find the connectivity matrix of the connectome of C. Elegans?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, experimental-neuroscience

I am trying to find the entire connectivity matrix for the [connectome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectome) of the roundworm [*C. elegans*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caenorhabditis_elegans). It is a much studied animal, as it features just a handful of neurons in its nervous system, 302 to be axact.

I've been looking forever and have come across [this website](http://www.dynamic-connectome.org/?page_id=25) that seems to have *parts* of the connectome (131 neurons and 277 neurons), but unfortunately it does not include the full connectome. [In the Worm Atlas](http://www.wormatlas.org/neuronalwiring.html), under section 2.1 Connectivity Data, it says it has all the data, but it doesn't seem to have the adjacency matrix for the connectome.

If anyone can direct me to a s**ource where I can find a connectivity matrix of the *C. elegans* connectome** that would be a great help to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full connectome of *C. elegans* (Fig. 1.) is described by [Farber (2012)](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/c-elegans-connectome/) and as far as I know, the most complete data on *C. elegans*, including its connectome is available from the [**OpenWorm Project** found here](http://www.openworm.org/downloads.html).

[image: connectome C. elegans]
<sup>Fig. 1. *C. elegans* connectome. image source: [Farber (2012)](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/c-elegans-connectome/)</sup>

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Farber, *Sci Am* February 2012](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/c-elegans-connectome/)</sub>

<sub>**Further reading**

**-** [Are there organisms with fewer than 1000 neurons?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/57594/are-there-organisms-with-fewer-than-1000-neurons/57601#57601)</sub>